# synchronous function call in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make synchronous call to functions in my node js code.

I am calling my functions like this

```
set_authentication();
set_file();

function  set_authentication(){
---
callback function
---
}
```

I want that my set_authentication() function should execute first completely and then set_file() should start execution but set_file() function start executing before the callback of set_authentication().

I have tried this using async also like

```
async.series(
        [
            // Here we need to call next so that async can execute the next function.
            // if an error (first parameter is not null) is passed to next, it will directly go to the final callback
            function (next) {
                set_looker_authentication_token();

            },
            // runs this only if taskFirst finished without an error
            function (next) {
                set_view_measure_file();
            }
        ],
        function(error, result){

        }
    );
```

but it also doesn't work.

I tried promise also

```
set_authentication().then(set_file(),console.error);

function  set_authentication(){
        ---
        callback function
        var myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      setTimeout(function(){
        resolve("Success!");
      }, 250);
    }); 
       ---
        }
```

here I am getting this error:- Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

I am new to node and js.

Comment: the Promise one doesn't work because you haven't returned the promise you created, also you have `then(set_file(),console.error)`, that will call set_file immediately since you have the `()` which tells it to call it instead of passing it as a reference: `then(set_file,console.error)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), because you call `.then` method of a returned promise:

```js
set_authentication().then(set_file);

function set_authentication() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {                 // <------ This is a thing
    setTimeout(function(){
     console.log('set_authentication() called');
     resolve("Success!");
    }, 250);
  });
}
        
function set_file(param) {
  console.log('set_file called');
  console.log(
    'received from set_authentication():', param);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer but There is a callback function inside my set_authentication() function If I use something like this.                                  function set_authentication() {
  callbackFunction();                                                                                                               return new Promise(resolve => {               
    setTimeout(function(){
     console.log('set_authentication() called');
     resolve("Success!");
    }, 250);
  });
}  still my set_file() is executed before the callback function.

Comment: Please, pay attention to the example. `callbackFunction` should be inside brackets `new Promise(resolve => { HERE })`.

Answer (score 1):

If `set_authentication` is async func, you need to pass `set_file` as callback to `set_authentication` function.

You may also consider to use promises as you wrote, but you need to implement it before you start chaining.

Comment: I tried passing set_file as callback also and calling it from set_authentication function but still my set_file Is getting called before the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

use `async.auto` like this:

```
 async.auto(
                {
                    first: function (cb, results) {
                        var status=true;
                        cb(null, status)
                    },
                    second: ['first', function (results, cb) {
                        var status = results.first;
                        console.log("result of first function",status)
                    }],
                },
                function (err, allResult) {
                   console.log("result of executing all function",allResult)

                }
            );
```